# Unable to create a manifest resource name for "Form1.resx"; Could not find "...Form1.cs"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

After i copied my project to another computer i got "Unable to create a manifest resource name for "From1.resx"; Could not find "...Form1.cs" " error. Both Pcs are 32bit win7 OS and installed vs2017 professional. How can solve this problem?
Thanks.

[image: Error sc!]

Comment: Can you explain how you did the copy?

Comment: Tried 2 ways: 1- copied project folder (9mb) 2-zipped project folder

Comment: You just need to create the same project with the same name of the form and then go to your previous file and open it using the notepad and copy it to your a new form.

Comment: I will try but why i cannot transport the project and run it?

Comment: Having *two* Form1.resx files is very unhealthy of course.  The one it complains is almost guaranteed to not be copied because of `..\\..`, two directories up from the project directory.  Problems like this are good enough reasons to create an account on github.com

Comment: @HansPassant there must be away to copy   project one computer to another. Can you give an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

1. Right Click on Solution Explorer.
2. Go to the file that does not have Designer View.
3. Exclude It From Project.
4. Include It From Project.

*Make sure that you are using the same **framework** as your old project

Comment: Thanks for answer Omar. When u say "exclude" u mean "Remove" right? Whıch files in the project should i remove and include (direct me usıng screenshot pls) i used for Form1.cs but it didnt work.

Comment: exclude from project it just removes it from your solution, not removing file from disk. try to exclude Form1.cs (Right Click exclude from project )from then include it .

Comment: There is no exclude option when form1.cs right clicked?