# how to fix the form "the item 'Form1.vb' does not exit in the project directory. it maybe have been moved ,rename or deleted

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When i try to open my form of my project there was a messagebox that pop to my form and it say" The item 'Form1.vb is not exist in the project directory. It maybe have been moved, rename or deleted.

sample images:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVOPD.png)

how do i open my form is there anyone can help me. :(((((((

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory...

Comment: do you want to add it? remove it? create it? is it missing? did you do an incorrect git merge? Help us help you by explaining as much as you can regarding what you have tried, what you expected and what happened

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the message in the error view; "Unable to create a manifest resource name for form1"

Try these answers;

[Unable to create a manifest resource name error in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942332/unable-to-create-a-manifest-resource-name-error-in-visual-studio-2008)

[Unable to create a manifest resource name for "Form1.resx"; Could not find "...Form1.cs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141105/unable-to-create-a-manifest-resource-name-for-form1-resx-could-not-find-f)

Comment: do you have other sample sir i try your suggest but it didn't work.

Comment: What should i do i don't want to create another project it takes a lot of time.... Please help me :(

Comment: this is happened after i reset my laptop and download a visual studio 2017.. all of my project has been unable to view the form as well as the code is unable to view.

Comment: ah perhaps try a re-install or repair of VS then?